# Listing filenames with exclusions with echo command in linux

Tags: linux, echo

How to list all filenames with echo command starting with 'a', but not 'aa'. For example 'aa', 'aaa' and 'aabb' must be excluded? I tried: echo a *[^aa] but this didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you should do `echo a[^a]*`

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing with `a*[^aa]` is catching file names which starts with **a** and does not contain **a** after that (anywhere) , for filenames which starts with a but not aa you should do

```
echo a[^a]*
```